# INFO: Maximum number of threads (200) created for connector with address null and port 8080

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services, connection

I am getting this error on AWS server.I am using tomcat server and have 2 application deployed on it.

Is this because of number of active threads issue. I restarted the server instance(which should release all the thread) but it is still giving this issue.

I have increases the maxThreads value from 200 to 500 in tomcat server.xml. But it didn't help.

Still I am not able to login in the system. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many clients are connecting to your Tomcat instance? If it's more than 200 (or 500), then you'll exhaust your thread pool and get this error.

Comment: What versions of everything? Take a thread dump to find out what your threads are doing.